# Error:No such property: FOR_RUNTIME for class: org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android **studio 3.0** and  classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` and `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`
and got the compile issue

> Error:No such property: FOR_RUNTIME for class:
>   org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage

Please help me out of this.

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file here if you have edited it.

Comment: This caused me a whole afternoon, and I am feel despair. I try to increase gradle version to 4.2.1 or 4.3.1 and down grade gradle to 2.3.3 or upgrade to 3.1.0 .and both not fix my issue.  I finally fix this by reset my JAVA_HOME with lasted jdk 1.8.0_153, I don't know what is the relationship, Thanks god I fix it so that I can continue to work. even I need to work later today to make up the time. Hope this can help others, reset JAVA_HOME.

Comment: did you add dimensions in your buildVariant in gradle file ?

Answer (score 2):

i also faced the same issue i solved it by updating the gradle version 
Update `Gradle version` to `4.2.1`

Comment: I am not solved this by just change to "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip"