# No such property: FOR_RUNTIME for class: org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio compile error:

`Error:No such property: FOR_RUNTIME for class: org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage`

Can`t fix this problem for 2 days .

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281344/errorno-such-property-for-runtime-for-class-org-gradle-api-attributes-usage)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please check your Android system log.
Usually it located at:

For Windows:

```
C:\User\yourusername\\.AndroidStudio3.1\system\log\idea.log
```

I encounter the same issue, and I got this error log:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FOR_RUNTIME for class: org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage
```

It means you have to upgrade the com.novoda.bintray-release to the latest version

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line: apply from: '../api.attributes

in your library's build gradle of your android project

Comment: i have no line like that 
`apply from: '../api.attributes`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have solved it. In my case, I was using Gradle local distribution so I changed it to use default gradle wrapper. And update your gradle to latest version in your project by simply copy the latest version and paste it to your project file.

Answer (score 0):

You must use older version of gradle. example:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going here: https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/releases

Look for the latest release and add it to the end of the:
'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.1' in "Build.gradle file"